# Powershell Define Powershell Objects

Tags: powershell

I like to define my variables in a structered fashion. Most MSDN blogs however do not do this.

For example:
    [object]myObj = ...

Is this the correct default format for all objects in Powershell?

Answer (score 9):

Use `PsObject` like this:

```
$o = new-Object PsObject -property @{Name='donald'; Kind='duck' }
```

You pass a hashtable as argument for `-property` parameter. Also you can create empty object and add properties later:

```
$o = New-Object PsObject
$o | Add-Member NoteProperty project myproj.csproj
$o | Add-Member NoteProperty Success $true
```

You can of course use pipe to `Add-Member`

```
$o = New-Object PsObject
# ...
$o | 
   Add-Member NoteProperty project myproj.csproj -pass |
   Add-Member NoteProperty Success $true
```

Comment: Shortcut: $O = [PSCustomObject] @{Name = 'Donald'; Kind='Duck'}
start from Powershell v3 (blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx) under 'New Conversion' section

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, you're asking a couple things:

1. Can you explicitly specify the type of a variable?
2. What type does Powershell use if you don't specify one yourself?

Powershell will certainly let you specify a type explicitly, but it will also infer types. Note that since all types inherit from `System.Object`, explicitly specifying `[object]` in a combined declaration/assignment statement has no value that I can see. The type system will still infer an appropriate child type. For example:

```
$x = 3
$x.GetType() # Returns 'Int32'

Remove-Variable x
[object] $x = 3
$x.GetType() # Returns 'Int32'

Remove-Variable x
[valuetype] $x = 3
$x.GetType() # Returns 'Int32'

Remove-Variable x
[int] $x = 3
$x.GetType() # Returns 'Int32'
```

If you split up the declaration and assignment, you can create a variable of type `Object`:

```
Remove-Variable x
$x = new-object -TypeName Object
$x.GetType() # Returns 'Object'
```

...but once you assign a value, the variable gets a new inferred type anyway:

```
$x = 3
$x.GetType() # Returns 'Int32'
```

While the type system will happily infer `Int32` when you specify `Object`, explicit types win when the inferred type would be incompatible. For example:

```
$x = 3          # Gets inferred type 'Int32'
[string] $x = 3 # Gets explicit type 'String'

$x = 'x'        # Gets inferred type 'String'
[char] $x = 'x' # Gets explicit type 'Char'
```

If your question is more geared toward defining and using custom object types, Stej's answer is excellent.

Comment: In your example, you didn't really split declaration and assignment. $x = new-object -TypeName Object is an assignment. And $x.GetType() returns the type of the value.

Answer (score 1):

Since Powershell 3 one can also parse HashTables to 
Custom Objects like:

```
[PSObject] $Piza = [PSCustomObject] @{
    Ingredients = 4
}
```

Or if you like to define more detailed types in your object 
you could use the -AsCustomObject Parameter from New-Module

```
[PSObject] $Piza = New-Module -AsCustomObject -ScriptBlock {
    [Guid]$id = [Guid]::NewGuid()
    [String] $Name = 'Macaroni' 

    Function TestFunction() {}

    # Dont forget to export your members and functions 
    # as this is built up as a module and stuffed into 
    # an object later
    Export-ModuleMember -Function * -Variable *
}
```

As there are no things as classes in posh you can add 
custom classnames and namespaces to your object 
that you can query later (pseudo instance ;)

```
$Piza.PSObject.TypeNames.Insert(0, 'Pizas.Macaroni')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you are asking

- How to create custom object in powershell?

In powershell, it is able to create an instance of .Net object by using **New-Object**. Like this

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate2("http://stackoverflow.com/")
$ie.Visible = $true
```

The code above create a com object which navigate your ie to stackoverflow.

And, If you want to create your own object, **PSObject** would be your choice. Like below

```
$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Name = "Your Name"
    Age = 30
}
```

When you call the object by using "$obj"

```
$obj
Age Name
--- ----
30 Your Name
```

If you are using powershell 3.0, you can get the same result with less typing like below

```
[PSCustomObject] @{
    Name = "Your Name"
    Age = 30
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creation of the PSObject object is the basis for access to all objects from the scripting language and provides an abstraction for the cmdlet developer and

It differs in different version of powershell..

New-Object PSObject –Property [HashTable]

```
     $Object = New-Object PSObject`                                       
     $Object | add-member Noteproperty LineNumber       $LineNumber                 
     $Object | add-member Noteproperty Date             $TodayDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create fast objects like that:

**$myVar = "" | select column1, column2, column3**

this will create object with 3 NoteProperties 
and you have access to every property on normal basis like

$myVar.column1

P.S. take under consideration that this is Selecte.System.String not System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject.

Still enough for keeping rows of data, exporting, accessing data cells.

Update: More flexible solution and still easy to implement would be Hashtable created like below.

**$myVar2 = @{**

**column1=value1**

**column2=value2**

**column3=value3**

**}**

This will create variable of type **System.Collections.Hashtable**

with some nice methods

regards
hermitagup